# How to disentangle system and brew python

Tags: python, macos

I don't know how I ended up with this setup (on macOS 10.15.5), but I can't exactly tell if I'm using the homebrew python or the system python. The following suggests that I'm using homebrew's python:

```
➜  ~ which python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3
➜  ~ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
➜  ~ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  38 Jul 26 22:09 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3
```

When I try to get similar info from within python, however, it seems like I am using the system python(?):

```
➜ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26)
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:48:26)
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)]
>>> print(sys.executable)
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8
```

I don't know how to reconcile the two. Which python am I using?

Comment: How about `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3`

Comment: @WaketZheng seems to link back to `../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`.

Comment: Then `ll ../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`

Comment: @WaketZheng `python3.8` in the same dir

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189145/how-does-sys-executable-determine-the-interpreter-path